# Calculating pi in c

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, pi

I'm trying to code a program that approximates pi using a certain equation. However, when I go run the code it outputs 4.8731472566 instead of 3.1415924576 and I was wondering if there were any mistakes in my code. Here's what I have so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i;

    printf("n = ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    double pi = 0.1; 
    double pi_1, pi_2, pi_3, pi_4, pi_5 = 0; //sets varibles that represent 4.0/((8*i)+1), etc. equal to zero 

    i = 0; // sets i equal to zero
    
    while(i <= n){ // starts a loop with i is less than non-negative interger n
        

        pi_1 = 4.0/((8*i)+1); //setting them equal to their respective parts of the equation
        pi_2 = 2.0/((8*i)+4);
        pi_3 = 1.0/((8*i)+5);
        pi_4 = 1.0/((8*i)+6);
        pi_5 = 1.0;

        int j = 0; //creating new interger j

        while(j <= i){ //as long as j isn't greater than i 
            pi_5 = pi_5*(1.0/16); //it will run the last part of the formula
            j++;
        }

        pi += pi * (pi_1 - pi_2 - pi_3 - pi_4 - pi_5); //sets pi = to the entire formula 
        i++;
    }
    
    

    printf("PI = %.10f\n", pi);
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the equation...

[image]

I've tried changing pi to different integers like 0.001 and 1 and that didn't work

Comment: Why is `pi` initialized to 0.1? You aren't using `pi_5` correctly, nor adding to your series scorrectly.

Comment: `pi` should start at 0, since you're computing a sum of terms. And the formula in the code is nothing like the formula in the picture.

Comment: `i = 0; // sets i equal to zero`?  The comment `// sets i equal to zero` merely repeats what the code does.  Comments like that are actually worse than useless because code changes over time.  What would you do if you saw this in code `i = 1; // sets i equal to zero` because someone updated the code but didn't update the comment?  Comments that explain *why* the code is doing something, or where the idea came from, are much better than just repeating what the code already says.

Comment: Also, your code is missing that the sum is divided by 16 raised to the ith power, not just 16.

Comment: @AndrewHenle it also looks as though the code divides by `16`  by `(i+1)` times, instead of `i` times.

Comment: @Han Li, note that  `double pi_1, pi_2, pi_3, pi_4, pi_5 = 0; //sets varibles that represent 4.0/((8*i)+1), etc. equal to zero` does **not** initialize variable**s**.  It initializes only one variable: `pi_5`.

Comment: @HanLi I suggest you make the code comments more informative – don't use them to explain how C works. For example `while(j <= i){ //as long as j isn't greater than i` has no *added value* and something like `// loop for power i` might be better.

Comment: @Han Li, Note that 10 terms are sufficient to achieve a good `double` pi.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things wrong in the way you calculate `pi`. `pi` should start from `0.0` and `pi += pi * (pi_1 - pi_2 - pi_3 - pi_4 - pi_5);` should not contain the `pi *`  part and you should multiply by `pi_5` instead and the `while` loops condition should be `j < i`.

---

I came up with this function (which makes use of `<math.h>`, instead of calculating the power with a loop). I am using `k` here since it is the same as used at the link I provided in the function to the formula.

```
double approximatePI(int steps) {
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe_formula

    double pi = 0.0;

    for (int k = 0; k < steps; ++k) {
        const double multiplicand = 1.0 / pow(16.0, k);
        const double minuend = 4.0 / (8.0 * k + 1.0);

        // if you add all of them and subtract then together its
        // the same result as if you subtract all of them individually
        const double subtrahend = 2.0 / (8.0 * k + 4.0) +
                            1.0 / (8.0 * k + 5.0) +
                            1.0 / (8.0 * k + 6.0);

        pi += multiplicand * (minuend - subtrahend);        
    }

    return pi;
}
```

---

Making this its own function makes it easier to use it in multiple spots. And btw if you post code on stackoverflow (or you just want to debug it yourself) it is easier and faster to test it if you provide some constant value for e.g. `n` (or what I called `steps` in my function) instead of using `scanf()` to get it from the user each time you run it.

Comment: Note that `steps` here is like OP's `n + 1`.

Comment: "if you add all of them and subtract then together its the same result as if you subtract all of them individually" --> not quite with floating-point math.  Yet not a major issue here either.

Comment: Nice that you included the [BBP link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe_formula).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what others suggest:

**Tip**: rather compute `pi_5` with a somewhat expensive loop or with a slow `1/pow(16,i)` call, use the prior value to quickly form the new one.

```
  double pi_5 = 1.0;
  for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    double pi_1 = 4.0 / ((8 * i) + 1);
    double pi_2 = 2.0 / ((8 * i) + 4);
    double pi_3 = 1.0 / ((8 * i) + 5);
    double pi_4 = 1.0 / ((8 * i) + 6);
    sum += (pi_1 - pi_2 - pi_3 - pi_4)*pi_5;
    pi_5 /= 16;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing the code, there seems to be a lot of unneeded variables and looping involved.  I do see that there has been an answer added, but I thought I would go ahead and toss in my simplified version which also utilizes the math.h file and math library.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int i, n;

    printf("n = ");
    i = scanf("%d", &n);

    double pi = 0.0;

    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)  // Use a simple "for loop" for the summation process
    {
        pi += (4.0/((8*i)+1) - 2.0/((8*i)+4) - 1.0/((8*i)+5) - 1.0/((8*i)+6)) / pow(16,i); // Sets pi = to the entire formula
    }

    printf("PI = %.10f\n", pi);
    return 0;
}
```

A simple "for loop" is substituted in the refactored code, and using the summation formula, only the "pi" variable is necessary.  Following was some sample output.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/PI/bin/Release$ ./PI
n = 6
PI = 3.1415926536
```

The only additional thing to point out is that when using the "math.h" include file, a reference in the linking portion of the build needs to be done, usually with an "-lm" as "m" is the math function library.